# What is an atom in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I thought that 'a is suppose to be an atom in scheme. But when I use an online [interpreter](http://sisc-scheme.org/sisc-online.php) and evalute the following I get back `#f`.

```
(atom? 'a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Scheme standard does not define `atom?`; the usual definition is

```
(define (atom? x) 
  (and (not (pair? x))
       (not (null? x))))
```

With that definition,

```
> (atom? 'a)
#t
```

so I think you are right and the SISC online REPL is wrong.

Comment: `(atom? 'a)` in chicken-scheme returns `#t`. So the repl is probably wrong.

Comment: I believe that the empty list is an atom, under the usual definition of atom.